# How can I trigger IISExpress to respond to changes in applicationhost.config

Tags: iis-express, applicationhost

I've updated

%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config

per the changes on this post:

http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/aspnet-web-api-compression

Namely, I've added

```
<httpCompression ...>
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" >
```

to compress JSON in Web API responses. But judging by the content-length and content-type in the response header, IISExpress isn't compressing the response and therefore the config changes are not taking affect.

I also restarted IISExpress.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Running IISExpress.exe and entering 'Q' to stop IIS Express didn't do the the trick.  But shutting down Visual Studio and then stopping IIS Express did.  Upon relaunching the VS, JSON data was then compressed.